# Is it possible to use Flask RestX wih Flask's 2.0+ async await?

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, flask-restful

Usage of async/await was presented in Flask 2.0. (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/async-await/)

I am using Flask-RestX so is it possible to use `async`/`await` in RestX requests handlers?

Something like:

```
@api.route('/try-async')
class MyResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(some_schema)
    async def get(self):
        result = await async_function()
        return result
```

is not working and when I try to reach this endpoint I'm getting error:

`TypeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable`

Is there any info on that?

Package versions:

```
flask==2.0.1
flask-restx==0.4.0
```

and I've also installed `flask[async]` as documentation suggests.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten around this by using an internal redirect

```
@api.route('/try-async')
class MyResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(some_schema)
    def get(self):
        return redirect(url_for('.hidden_async'), code=307)

@api.route('/hidden-async', methods=['GET'])
async def hidden_async():
    result = await async_function()
    return result
```

Redirecting with `code=307` will ensure any method and body are unchanged after the redirect ([Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307)). So passing data to the async function is possible as well.

```
@api.route('/try-async')
class MyResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(some_schema)
    def post(self):
        return redirect(url_for('.hidden_async'), code=307)

@api.route('/hidden-async', methods=['POST'])
async def hidden_async():
    data = request.get_json()
    tasks = [async_function(d) for d in data]
    result = await asyncio.gather(tasks)
    return result
```

Comment: I dont think this is what you want, the flask request will not be asynchronous, only the hidden route which the client doesnt actually call... ie flask will not be able to process multiple request asynchronously